# most efficient AABB vs Ray collision algorithms

Tags: collision-detection, aabb

Is there a known 'most efficient' algorithm for AABB vs Ray collision detection?

I recently stumbled accross Arvo's AABB vs Sphere collision algorithm, and I am wondering if there is a similarly noteworthy algorithm for this.

One must have condition for this algorithm is that I need to have the option of querying the result for the distance from the ray's origin to the point of collision. having said this, if there is another, faster algorithm which does not return distance, then in addition to posting one that does, also posting that algorithm would be very helpful indeed.

Please also state what the function's return argument is, and how you use it to return distance or a 'no-collision' case. For example, does it have an out parameter for the distance as well as a bool return value? or does it simply return a float with the distance, vs a value of -1 for no collision?

(For those that don't know: AABB = Axis Aligned Bounding Box)

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you will still get false positives with this algorithm. You are right that if all corners are on same side when checking the 3 axis, there is no collision. But it seems like you can still have the condition where all 3 axis have points on both sides and still have no collision. I generally check to see if entry/exit distances overlap on all three slabs to know for sure. It's from the Geometric tools site.

Comment: Why the must have condition for distance query? If there is an even faster algorithm for the case when you do not need the distance, don't you want to know about it, too?

Comment: well, no, not really. I need to know at what distance the collision happens.

Comment: actually I suppose you're right, I'll edit the question.

Comment: As I posted in your other thread, there's a good resource for these types of algorithms here: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

Comment: really great resource, but which is the most efficient?

Comment: Are you writing a voxel raytracer, or are you writing a typical 3D engine with a world based on arbitary polygons/polyhedra?

Comment: @Tetrad you're basically saying [RTFM](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html). While I agree with the sentiment sometimes, it's not really helpful to have a bunch of collision questions, the answer to which is that same table. Close/delete or give a good answer

Comment: @NickWiggill the latter

Comment: The question says _algorithm_, everybody is posting _code_ with no verbal description of _algorithm_.

Comment: @bobobobo apologies, I was assuming everyone on this site could code. I'll try to rephrase in future.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Andrew Woo, who along with John Amanatides developed the raymarching algorithm (DDA) used ubiquitously in raytracers, wrote ["Fast Ray-Box Intersection"](https://web.archive.org/web/20090803054252/http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gems/RayBox.c) (alternative source [here](https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/RayBox.c)) which was published in Graphics Gems, 1990, pp. 395-396. Rather than being built specifically for integration through a grid (eg. a voxel volume) as DDA is (see zacharmarz' answer), this algorithm is specifically suited to worlds that are not evenly subdivided, such as your typical polyhedra world found in most 3D games.

The approach provides support for 3D, and optionally does backface culling. The algorithm is derived from the same principles of integration used in DDAs, so it is *very* quick.  More detail can be found in the original Graphics Gems volume (1990).

Many other approaches specifically for Ray-AABB to be found at [realtimerendering.com](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html).

EDIT: An alternative, branchless approach -- which would be desirable on both GPU & CPU -- may be found [here](https://tavianator.com/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections/). The actual code, including the max() on the return test, is available [here](https://tavianator.com/cgit/dimension.git/tree/libdimension/bvh/bvh.c#n196).

Comment: ah! you beat me to it, I just came across it this morning. Great find!

Comment: Pleasure, Sir. I'd also suggest comparing any algorithms you find on [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/556970-relative-speed-of-various-math-operations-and-comparisons/) sort of basis. (There are more official lists like this elsewhere, but can't find any right now.)

Comment: The article is [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=fvA7zLEFWZgC&pg=PA394&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: A well commented implementation of Woo's algorithm may be found [here](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~pang/160/f98/Gems/FinalFTP/Light/raybox.c).

Comment: The two links you provide generate "Not found" and "Forbidden" errors respectively...

Comment: Hi @GiorgioLiggio and thanks for the heads up. I've included details on the article in my answer - this should help people find it even if links break. For now, here is a [reference implementation](https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/RayBox.c).

Comment: However, the link for the branchless version you mention in your edit is also broken and about that one you don't give any reference info

Comment: How about [this](https://tavianator.com/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections/)? Just search "raybox.c branchless".

Comment: You should really update your answer to fix the 2 dead links.

Comment: Not sure it's procedure to mention, but I fixed the dead links.

Comment: This function does not give the angle of intersection, something that I need. And I'm too bad at maths to figure it out myself.

Comment: To anyone using the "branch-less approach", be warned that it will fail if the ray's origin starts along one of the planes of the box, and it is also parallel to that plane. IE, if we get a "line hit" or "plane hit" (not sure the term). In that case the result is a nan value, and the results are junk. Additional checks need to be added to fix that. Also, if using C++ std::min and std::max, it is far from branchless depending on implementation.

Comment: @TylerShellberg Sometimes you can also nudge the _data_ to prevent these pathological cases from occurring. This can be a more performant solution than adding additional runtime checks; however, it's not _always_ possible.

Answer (score 60):

What I have been using earlier in my raytracer:

```
// r.dir is unit direction vector of ray
dirfrac.x = 1.0f / r.dir.x;
dirfrac.y = 1.0f / r.dir.y;
dirfrac.z = 1.0f / r.dir.z;
// lb is the corner of AABB with minimal coordinates - left bottom, rt is maximal corner
// r.org is origin of ray
float t1 = (lb.x - r.org.x)*dirfrac.x;
float t2 = (rt.x - r.org.x)*dirfrac.x;
float t3 = (lb.y - r.org.y)*dirfrac.y;
float t4 = (rt.y - r.org.y)*dirfrac.y;
float t5 = (lb.z - r.org.z)*dirfrac.z;
float t6 = (rt.z - r.org.z)*dirfrac.z;

float tmin = max(max(min(t1, t2), min(t3, t4)), min(t5, t6));
float tmax = min(min(max(t1, t2), max(t3, t4)), max(t5, t6));

// if tmax < 0, ray (line) is intersecting AABB, but the whole AABB is behind us
if (tmax < 0)
{
    t = tmax;
    return false;
}

// if tmin > tmax, ray doesn't intersect AABB
if (tmin > tmax)
{
    t = tmax;
    return false;
}

t = tmin;
return true;
```

If this returns true, it's intersecting, if it returns false, it's not intersecting.

If you use the same ray many times, you can precompute `dirfrac` (only division in whole intersection test). And then it's really fast. And you have also length of ray until intersection (stored in `t`).

Comment: would it be possible to provide a key for what your variable names mean?

Comment: I tried to add some explanation in comments. So: "r" is ray, "r.dir" is its unit direction vector, "r.org" is origin, from which you shoot ray, "dirfrac" is just optimization, because you can use it always for the same ray (you don't have to do division) and it means 1 / r.dir. Then "lb" is corner of AABB with all 3 coordinates minimal and "rb" is oposite - corner with maximum coordinates. Output parametr "t" is length of vector from origin to intersection.

Comment: what does the function definition look like? Is it possible to find out the distance that the collision occurred on the ray?

Comment: function returns distance ('t' is distance). And function definition can be whatever you want ;) You should pass ray, lb and rt.

Comment: it seems to me like the return type for this code would be a bool?

Comment: also where are dirfrac and t declared?

Comment: ah yes, and what are max and min in the third block of code? rb and lb are essentially max and min for the bounding box, so what are they?

Comment: It's not whole function. I just copied a bit of code which was important. You should not copy this code, but only use it as reference. And sorry, I though it returns 't' - t is distance. So if you want to get distance, just return 't'.

Comment: would it be possible to just tell us what min, max, t and difrac are and where they are defined? Without this info I can't use any of this.

Comment: oh wait, max and min are inbuilt functions right? OK so just what t and difrac are would be great!

Comment: dirfrac is vector, it has x, y and z components. And t is float (or double). It's distance from ray's origin to collision.

Comment: great! thank you. so what exactly is dirfrac, and how do you use it?

Comment: dirfrac is just for optimization. If you compute many intersections for one ray, dirfrac is the same for the whole time. Computation of dirfrac containts division, which is expensive operation. And it's (1 / dir) - but I compute it for each component separately.

Comment: I have implemented this code and it does not seem to work. Does it depend at all on the handedness of the coordinate space or something like that?

Comment: No. It doesn't. And it worked for me for a long time.

Comment: and it works with a normalised ray, right?

Comment: I figured out why it's breaking for me - ray direction has a z value of 0, so the z component of diffrac is infinite. Can I just take out the dirfrac part?

Comment: I think it would be better to use something like FLT_MIN (or really small number = almost equal to zero) for your Z component, when it's zero. And I don't understand what you mean by: Take out the dirfrac part. It's part of computation, so you can't just delete it.

Comment: oh, I thought you said it was just for optimisation. So how do you deal with rays that have one or more zero components in your ray tracer?

Comment: I just add flt_min (or really small number) to that component. You will need division in all cases. But you can compute this division just once for each ray, not every time you want to compute ray/box collision.

Comment: so what does your algorithm mean when it returns an intersection but that intersection has a negative number? tmin is sometimes returned as a negative number.

Comment: ah, it's when the origin is inside the box

Comment: Yes. Or whole BBox is behind origin :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, although I have done some unit tests now and found that there are other algorithms that can be more efficient, you have answered so many of my questions so I think you deserve the bounty.

Comment: Just a quickie - does it works if minimum of bounding box is -1, -1, -1 and maximum 1, 1, 1 and origin of ray is 1, 1, 10 and its direction is 0, 0, -1? I'm asking because I cannot make it work somehow...

Comment: It should work in any case - and is working for me.

Comment: This code does have one catch -- if your ray origin lies on the face of a bounding box and your ray is projected along the axis orthogonal to that face, you will end up with NaNs, as you are multiplying zero and Inf.

Comment: +1 For making the code well-presented and well-commented.

Comment: This code fails to work if one of the ray direction vectors is zero because one cannot divide by zero.

Comment: @josch if it's parrallel, it is infinite on those axis (since this is axis aligned), and unlike ints, floats do not automatically cause errors on division by zero, so you should be able to work around that fairly easily (or just test for infinity).

Comment: Does it find the real t value? `t = tmin` I doubt it may only find a rang of t.

Answer (score 19):

Nobody described the algorithm here, but the [Graphics Gems algorithm](http://books.google.ca/books?id=fvA7zLEFWZgC&pg=PA394&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) is simply:

1. Using your ray's direction vector, determine which 3 of the 6 candidate planes *would be hit first*.  If your (unnormalized) ray direction vector is (-1, 1, -1), then the 3 planes that are possible to be hit are +x, -y, and +z.
2. Of the 3 candidate planes, do find the t-value for the intersection for each.  Accept the plane that gets the *largest* **t** value as being the plane that got hit, **and check that the hit is within the box**.  The diagram in the text makes this clear:

[image]

My implementation:

```
bool AABB::intersects( const Ray& ray )
{
  // EZ cases: if the ray starts inside the box, or ends inside
  // the box, then it definitely hits the box.
  // I'm using this code for ray tracing with an octree,
  // so I needed rays that start and end within an
  // octree node to COUNT as hits.
  // You could modify this test to (ray starts inside and ends outside)
  // to qualify as a hit if you wanted to NOT count totally internal rays
  if( containsIn( ray.startPos ) || containsIn( ray.getEndPoint() ) )
    return true ; 

  // the algorithm says, find 3 t's,
  Vector t ;

  // LARGEST t is the only one we need to test if it's on the face.
  for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
  {
    if( ray.direction.e[i] > 0 ) // CULL BACK FACE
      t.e[i] = ( min.e[i] - ray.startPos.e[i] ) / ray.direction.e[i] ;
    else
      t.e[i] = ( max.e[i] - ray.startPos.e[i] ) / ray.direction.e[i] ;
  }

  int mi = t.maxIndex() ;
  if( BetweenIn( t.e[mi], 0, ray.length ) )
  {
    Vector pt = ray.at( t.e[mi] ) ;

    // check it's in the box in other 2 dimensions
    int o1 = ( mi + 1 ) % 3 ; // i=0: o1=1, o2=2, i=1: o1=2,o2=0 etc.
    int o2 = ( mi + 2 ) % 3 ;

    return BetweenIn( pt.e[o1], min.e[o1], max.e[o1] ) &&
           BetweenIn( pt.e[o2], min.e[o2], max.e[o2] ) ;
  }

  return false ; // the ray did not hit the box.
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm surprised to see that no one has mentioned the branchless slab method by Tavian

```
bool intersection(box b, ray r) {
    double tx1 = (b.min.x - r.x0.x)*r.n_inv.x;
    double tx2 = (b.max.x - r.x0.x)*r.n_inv.x;

    double tmin = min(tx1, tx2);
    double tmax = max(tx1, tx2);

    double ty1 = (b.min.y - r.x0.y)*r.n_inv.y;
    double ty2 = (b.max.y - r.x0.y)*r.n_inv.y;

    tmin = max(tmin, min(ty1, ty2));
    tmax = min(tmax, max(ty1, ty2));

    return tmax >= tmin;
}
```

Full explanation: https://tavianator.com/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections/

Comment: this is the fastest currently know method. note that modern min/max are often implemented branchless - thus the branchless-ness of the slab method.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what are these properties of the ray r? is r.n a normalized direction vec2? is r.n_inv = -r.n? is r.x0 the origin vec2 of the ray?

Comment: The same author wrote a follow-up blog post for handling some corner cases: https://tavianator.com/2015/ray_box_nan.html

Answer (score 4):

This is my 3D ray / AABox intersection I've been using:

```
bool intersectRayAABox2(const Ray &ray, const Box &box, int& tnear, int& tfar)
{
    Vector3d T_1, T_2; // vectors to hold the T-values for every direction
    double t_near = -DBL_MAX; // maximums defined in float.h
    double t_far = DBL_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //we test slabs in every direction
        if (ray.direction[i] == 0){ // ray parallel to planes in this direction
            if ((ray.origin[i] < box.min[i]) || (ray.origin[i] > box.max[i])) {
                return false; // parallel AND outside box : no intersection possible
            }
        } else { // ray not parallel to planes in this direction
            T_1[i] = (box.min[i] - ray.origin[i]) / ray.direction[i];
            T_2[i] = (box.max[i] - ray.origin[i]) / ray.direction[i];

            if(T_1[i] > T_2[i]){ // we want T_1 to hold values for intersection with near plane
                swap(T_1,T_2);
            }
            if (T_1[i] > t_near){
                t_near = T_1[i];
            }
            if (T_2[i] < t_far){
                t_far = T_2[i];
            }
            if( (t_near > t_far) || (t_far < 0) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    tnear = t_near; tfar = t_far; // put return values in place
    return true; // if we made it here, there was an intersection - YAY
}
```

Comment: What are `tnear` and `tfar`?

Comment: The intersection is between [tnear, tfar].

Answer (score 4):

Here is an optimized version of the above which I use for GPU:

```
__device__ float rayBoxIntersect ( float3 rpos, float3 rdir, float3 vmin, float3 vmax )
{
   float t[10];
   t[1] = (vmin.x - rpos.x)/rdir.x;
   t[2] = (vmax.x - rpos.x)/rdir.x;
   t[3] = (vmin.y - rpos.y)/rdir.y;
   t[4] = (vmax.y - rpos.y)/rdir.y;
   t[5] = (vmin.z - rpos.z)/rdir.z;
   t[6] = (vmax.z - rpos.z)/rdir.z;
   t[7] = fmax(fmax(fmin(t[1], t[2]), fmin(t[3], t[4])), fmin(t[5], t[6]));
   t[8] = fmin(fmin(fmax(t[1], t[2]), fmax(t[3], t[4])), fmax(t[5], t[6]));
   t[9] = (t[8] < 0 || t[7] > t[8]) ? NOHIT : t[7];
   return t[9];
}
```

Comment: converted this for unity use, and it was faster than builtin bounds.IntersectRay https://gist.github.com/unitycoder/8d1c2905f2e9be693c78db7d9d03a102

Comment: How can I interpret the returned value? Is it something like the Euclidean distance between origin and intersection point?

Comment: What value is the distance to the box?

Comment: Is this really more optimal for GPUs? I'm seeing it perform almost 50% worse than the nested if-else version on 1080 cards with complex geometry.. I think the problem is that you could have detected a box miss in a lot of cases right from the x dimension and skipped all the rest. But in this version you have to calculate x, y and z's min and maxs, and only then detect box hit in one go.

Answer (score 2):

I recently achieved over 61 billion ray/box intersections per second using AVX2 on a Threadripper 3960X (~2 billion single-threaded, ~1.9 cycles per box): https://tavianator.com/2022/ray_box_boundary.html.  I don't know what the state of the art is exactly, but that seems like more than enough :)

The unvectorized implementation looks like this.  It's a simple implementation of the slab method that handles edge cases:

```
void intersections(
    const struct ray *ray,
    size_t nboxes,
    const struct box boxes[nboxes],
    float ts[nboxes])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nboxes; ++i) {
        const struct box *box = &boxes[i];
        float tmin = 0.0, tmax = ts[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            float t1 = (box->min[j] - ray->origin[j]) * ray->dir_inv[j];
            float t2 = (box->max[j] - ray->origin[j]) * ray->dir_inv[j];

            tmin = min(max(t1, tmin), max(t2, tmin));
            tmax = max(min(t1, tmax), min(t2, tmax));
        }

        ts[i] = tmin <= tmax ? tmin : ts[i];
    }
}
```

The vectorized version is similar, packing 8 boxes per struct: https://tavianator.com/2022/ray_box_boundary.html#vectorization

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to investigate is rasterizing the front and backfaces of your bounding box in two seperate buffers.  Render the x,y,z values as rgb (this works best for a bounding box with one corner at (0,0,0) and the opposite at (1,1,1).

Obviously, this has limited use but I found it great for rendering simple volumes.

For more detail and code:

http://www.daimi.au.dk/~trier/?page_id=98

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Line vs AABB code I've been using:

```
namespace {
    //Helper function for Line/AABB test.  Tests collision on a single dimension
    //Param:    Start of line, Direction/length of line,
    //          Min value of AABB on plane, Max value of AABB on plane
    //          Enter and Exit "timestamps" of intersection (OUT)
    //Return:   True if there is overlap between Line and AABB, False otherwise
    //Note:     Enter and Exit are used for calculations and are only updated in case of intersection
    bool Line_AABB_1d(float start, float dir, float min, float max, float& enter, float& exit)
    {
        //If the line segment is more of a point, just check if it's within the segment
        if(fabs(dir) < 1.0E-8)
            return (start >= min && start <= max);

        //Find if the lines overlap
        float   ooDir = 1.0f / dir;
        float   t0 = (min - start) * ooDir;
        float   t1 = (max - start) * ooDir;

        //Make sure t0 is the "first" of the intersections
        if(t0 > t1)
            Math::Swap(t0, t1);

        //Check if intervals are disjoint
        if(t0 > exit || t1 < enter)
            return false;

        //Reduce interval based on intersection
        if(t0 > enter)
            enter = t0;
        if(t1 < exit)
            exit = t1;

        return true;
    }
}

//Check collision between a line segment and an AABB
//Param:    Start point of line segement, End point of line segment,
//          One corner of AABB, opposite corner of AABB,
//          Location where line hits the AABB (OUT)
//Return:   True if a collision occurs, False otherwise
//Note:     If no collision occurs, OUT param is not reassigned and is not considered useable
bool CollisionDetection::Line_AABB(const Vector3D& s, const Vector3D& e, const Vector3D& min, const Vector3D& max, Vector3D& hitPoint)
{
    float       enter = 0.0f;
    float       exit = 1.0f;
    Vector3D    dir = e - s;

    //Check each dimension of Line/AABB for intersection
    if(!Line_AABB_1d(s.x, dir.x, min.x, max.x, enter, exit))
        return false;
    if(!Line_AABB_1d(s.y, dir.y, min.y, max.y, enter, exit))
        return false;
    if(!Line_AABB_1d(s.z, dir.z, min.z, max.z, enter, exit))
        return false;

    //If there is intersection on all dimensions, report that point
    hitPoint = s + dir * enter;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to the code posted by zacharmarz.
I got this code from the book 'Real-Time Collision Detection' by Christer Ericson under the section '5.3.3  Intersecting Ray or Segment Against Box'

```
// Where your AABB is defined by left, right, top, bottom

// The direction of the ray
var dx:Number = point2.x - point1.x;
var dy:Number = point2.y - point1.y;

var min:Number = 0;
var max:Number = 1;

var t0:Number;
var t1:Number;

// Left and right sides.
// - If the line is parallel to the y axis.
if(dx == 0){
    if(point1.x < left || point1.x > right) return false;
}
// - Make sure t0 holds the smaller value by checking the direction of the line.
else{
    if(dx > 0){
        t0 = (left - point1.x)/dx;
        t1 = (right - point1.x)/dx;
    }
    else{
        t1 = (left - point1.x)/dx;
        t0 = (right - point1.x)/dx;
    }

    if(t0 > min) min = t0;
    if(t1 < max) max = t1;
    if(min > max || max < 0) return false;
}

// The top and bottom side.
// - If the line is parallel to the x axis.
if(dy == 0){
    if(point1.y < top || point1.y > bottom) return false;
}
// - Make sure t0 holds the smaller value by checking the direction of the line.
else{
    if(dy > 0){
        t0 = (top - point1.y)/dy;
        t1 = (bottom - point1.y)/dy;
    }
    else{
        t1 = (top - point1.y)/dy;
        t0 = (bottom - point1.y)/dy;
    }

    if(t0 > min) min = t0;
    if(t1 < max) max = t1;
    if(min > max || max < 0) return false;
}

// The point of intersection
ix = point1.x + dx * min;
iy = point1.y + dy * min;
return true;
```

Comment: this is 2d, yes?

Comment: This is only 2D, yes. Also, the code does is not as well thought as zacharmarz's, which takes care of reducing the number of divisions and tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have added to @zacharmarz answer to handle when the ray origin is inside of the AABB. In this case tmin will be negative and behind the ray so tmax is the first intersection between the ray and AABB.

```
// r.dir is unit direction vector of ray
dirfrac.x = 1.0f / r.dir.x;
dirfrac.y = 1.0f / r.dir.y;
dirfrac.z = 1.0f / r.dir.z;
// lb is the corner of AABB with minimal coordinates - left bottom, rt is maximal corner
// r.org is origin of ray
float t1 = (lb.x - r.org.x)*dirfrac.x;
float t2 = (rt.x - r.org.x)*dirfrac.x;
float t3 = (lb.y - r.org.y)*dirfrac.y;
float t4 = (rt.y - r.org.y)*dirfrac.y;
float t5 = (lb.z - r.org.z)*dirfrac.z;
float t6 = (rt.z - r.org.z)*dirfrac.z;

float tmin = max(max(min(t1, t2), min(t3, t4)), min(t5, t6));
float tmax = min(min(max(t1, t2), max(t3, t4)), max(t5, t6));

// if tmax < 0, ray (line) is intersecting AABB, but the whole AABB is behind us
if (tmax < 0)
{
    t = tmax;
    return false;
}

// if tmin > tmax, ray doesn't intersect AABB
if (tmin > tmax)
{
    t = tmax;
    return false;
}

// if tmin < 0 then the ray origin is inside of the AABB and tmin is behind the start of the ray so tmax is the first intersection
if(tmin < 0) {
  t = tmax;
} else {
  t = tmin;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

### C++ Code

Here is a quasi-branchless and very robust version written in C++:

```cpp
ray_intersection intersect(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, vec3 box_min, vec3 box_max) {
    vec3 t0 = (box_min - origin) / direction;
    vec3 t1 = (box_max - origin) / direction;
    vec3 min = ray_box_min(t0, t1); // entry points per plane
    vec3 max = ray_box_max(t0, t1); // exit points per plane
    double t_min = std::fmax(std::fmax(min.x, min.y), min.z);
    double t_max = std::fmin(std::fmin(max.x, max.y), max.z);
    return { t_min, t_max };
}
```

This also requires the use of two utility functions:

```cpp
double ray_box_min(double x, double y) {
    return std::isnan(x) || std::isnan(y) ? -inf : std::fmin(x, y);
}

double ray_box_max(double x, double y) {
    return std::isnan(x) || std::isnan(y) ? +inf : std::fmax(x, y);
}

vec3 ray_box_min(vec3 a, vec3 b) {
    return { ray_box_min(a.x, b.x), ray_box_min(a.y, b.y), ray_box_min(a.z, b.z) };
}

vec3 ray_box_max(vec3 a, vec3 b) {
    return { ray_box_max(a.x, b.x), ray_box_max(a.y, b.y), ray_box_max(a.z, b.z) };
}
```

### Explanation

This implements the well-known [Slab method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_method).

All operations including `/` and `min`/`max` are component-wise when applied to vectors in this code.

We cannot use regular `std::fmin` but must use a custom `ray_box_min` for numerical stability. If the ray origin is inside a box plane and the ray direction is parallel to the box plane, the first division yields NaN. We replace this with `-inf` and `+inf` depending on the operation. This results in the value getting replaced by others when computing `t_min` or `t_max`.

If you can guarantee that the ray origin is outside the box, you can use a regular component-wise `min` and `max` instead of the `ray_box_` variants.

#### Interpreting the results

- `t_min` is the furthest entry point
- `t_max` is the closest exit point

From these values, we can obtain all sorts of properties:

- If `t_min <= t_max`, the intersection is not a miss.

  - If also `t_min > 0`, the intersection is completely in front.
  - If also `t_max < 1`, the intersection is completely behind.

    - If also `t_min < 0 && t_max > 0`, the ray origin is inside the box.
- If `t_min` is NaN or `t_max` is NaN, the ray direction is the zero-vector.
- If `t_min == 0`, the ray origin lies on the box surface.
- If `t_min == t_max`, the box has no volume, or an edge or corner was hit. Either way, the intersection is a single point, not a line segment.